# How to restore Windows in GRUB2 UEFI

Tags: boot, multi-boot, grub, uefi, grub2

I've installed Fedora 26 onto a system that has Windows 10 on it.  I can boot into Fedora but now I can not boot into Windows 10.

I have entered into the grub/boot shell, and identified the Windows partition as `(hd0,gpt3)` as follows:

```
grub> ls -l
```

> Partition hd0,gpt3: Filesystem type ntfs - Label 'OS', UUID ... - Partition start at 644096KiB - Total size 326339584KiB

I also see

> Partition  hd0,gpt1: Filesystem type fat - Label 'ESP', UUIS ... - Partition starts at 1024KiB - Total size 512000KiB

How can I boot into that partition from the grub shell?

How can I add a menu entry for that partition?

Comment: `set root=(hd0,gpt1); chainloader EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi; boot`; better use `search -u UUID_OF_ESP -s` instead of `set root=(hd0,gpt1)` when you form a menuentry in grub.cfg

Comment: `boot` is not needed for a menuentry. booting via direct commands probably needs it, not exactly sure for the case of `chainloader`

Comment: How come GRUB installation has not detected Windows? "update-grub2" should do.

Comment: @TomYan Thanks.  I get `error: invalid file name 'EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi'`.  Any idea?  This is Windows 10 Professional if that makes any difference.  Is there a command to find out what files exist in that partition?

Comment: @snayob That's a good question - I also expected it to detect Windows.  I don't have a command `update-grub2`, nor `grub2-update`.  I tried `dnf reinstall grub2` and that didn't add such a command either.  This is Fedora 26 KDE spinoff, if that makes a difference.

Comment: @TomYan Searching for that path I see that I was missing a leading `/`, so `chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi` now gave me a different error: `error: invalid signature`.  Any thoughts?  Thank you.  p.s. I see this https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/69675/grub2-windows-entry-throws-invalid-signature/ I will try to reinstall Fedora accordingly.

Comment: Sorry I missed the `/`. The error could be due to the fact that your grub isn't of the right variant. You might have BIOS grub ("i386-pc") which cannot chainload UEFI Windows Boot Manager. You can see if there's an `ntldr` command available in the grub shell, if it does, you have the wrong variant of grub (which is probably because your fedora installation medium wasn't booted in UEFI mode).

Comment: @TomYan Yes, `ntldr` exists.  Thank you for your help.  Please post it as _answer_ and I will be happy to accept it.

Comment: p.s. Do I need to reinstall Fedora or is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

I have reinstalled Fedora and now I have Windows again in the boot menu.  Things to pay attention to:

- Booting with the USB installation medium plugged in had 2 different options: Legacy (BIOS) mode, and UEFI mode.  As @TomYan pointed out, I must have selected the wrong mode initially, which caused this whole problem.  I should have paid attention and selected to boot the USB in UEFI mode.

I created the following partitions, probably larger than needed but I have enough disk space so no issue there for me:

```
  /boot/efi     EFI System     256 MiB
  /boot         Ext4           768 MiB
  /             Ext4            56 GiB
  swap          Swap             8 GiB
```

Comment: For the benefit of others: Booting the installation medium in the wrong mode (typically BIOS rather than EFI) is a common mistake. When dual-booting with an existing EFI-mode installation of Windows, the common advice to enable BIOS/CSM/legacy support in the firmware is *very* bad advice that can lead to this trouble. There's less and less need for BIOS-mode boot support these days, so that support should generally be left disabled.